# Problem with parametric integral with variable bounds

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, assignment

```mathematica
d[p_, B_] := \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-B\), \(+B\)]\(Cos[
    p\ x] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)
 Plot[d[x, 2], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

I want to see the graph of $\delta(p)=\int_{-B}^{+B} \cos px \operatorname{d}\! x$.
So I define a function $d(p,B)=\int_{-B}^{+B} \cos px \operatorname{d}\! x$. I try to plot $d(p,2)$ or $d(p,3)$. But this doesn't work. Why?

Note that I used `setDelayed` operator `:=` because I would like it to be evaluated only when `B` is given. But this is wrong.

- Turns out, when I use `=` instead of `:=`, it works. But I still want to know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at what you get if you define:

[image]

and then call:

```
d[x, 2]
```

Now you have:

[image]

and "p" is now part of the dummy ingeration variable, what evaluates to:

[image]

There is no "x" left to plot.

Comment: ...................... Forgive me but this design is really dummy ...... although I believe it must benefit programming in other ways, otherwise the Mathematica team won't make it like this.

Comment: Dear @Neo, you are right that this can be confusing. To avoid this, you could use `d[p_,B_]:=Module[{x},Integrate[Cos[p*x],{x,-B,B}]]`, then the integration variable `x` and the symbol `x` that you pass in are two different symbols. The design is certainly deliberate. For example, some people expect that they can write `integrate01[f_] := Integrate[f,{x,0,1}]` and that when they call `integrate01[x^2]` it will give them $\int_0^1 x^2 dx = 1/3$ and not `x^2`.